# open/closed state based on time records in database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a mySQL table to indicate weather the shop is open or closed, based on time frames:

```
 shift table
--------------
 shift_id
 day_of_week    (1-7 : Monday-Sunday)
 open_time      (time, default NULL)
 close_time     (time, default NULL)
 type           (1 || 2)
```

Explanation of field type: 
**1** indicates the first timeframe within the same day and **2** indicates that the timeframe is the second timeframe within the same day. 
For example shop opens on 13:00 - 15:00 AND 18:00 - 01:00.

I am getting the current day using the method below:

```
$jd = cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN,date("m"),date("d"),date("Y"));
    $day = jddayofweek($jd, 0);

    switch($day){
        case 0:
            $curDay = 7;
        break;
        default:
            $curDay = $day;
        break;
    }
    return $curDay;
```

I am getting the current time using the method below:

```
$timeString = "%H:%i:%s";
$curTime = mdate($timeString, time());
```

**Complex example follows**:
**Current day**: Monday
**Current time**: 02:00.
**Sunday timeframe**: 15:00 - 18:00 and 21:00 - 02:30.
**Monday timeframe**: 08:30 - 15:30.

> Clearly the shift is **OPEN** but based on Sunday s timeframe and not on Monday s which is the current day.

What is the best way to query my table (or alter my table if needed) or the 100% accurate method to define each time if the shift is open or closed, in a given time of a given day ?

Comment: Yes. Its a tricky one, because the shift for example Monday can have 2 time frames, in which maybe the second timeframe ends on Tuesday. See my example.

Comment: @JaredFarrish the article you mentioned tries to find a solution for if timeframe covers another timeframe.

Comment: Oh right. When I first read it, it sounded just like that other one. Darn. That diagram on top is really hard to read.

Comment: Yeah, nevermind. I'm not so sharp right now I guess.

Comment: @JaredFarrish thank you for trying. I have 1s and 2s because I want max of 2 timeframes within a day. If a "now" time is between a timeframe I don t have to mind if there s an overlap by the timeframe settings. I just want a safe way to indicate if it is within boundaries even if a timeframe exceeds to the next day. Which next day of course could be Monday (Sunday -> Monday).

Comment: What is the use case? How will the information be used? Management reports? It sounds more complicated than the facts, which are capturedc by the date column. So there must be some business logic at work here.

Comment: You could use UNIX timestamps too. That's day, week, night and morning agnostic. You just give it a date, it finds out how many seconds have elapsed since an arbitrary date long in the past, and now you're just doing a calculation or aggregate of the possible shift times (maybe in a temporary table) and searching for shifts that intersect your given timestamp. It's just numbers.

Comment: A little bit dirty solution without getting changing much. How about restricting the column (whichever exceeds 23:59:59) and adding the rest to another new column say, `extra`. While searching, check in the range adding the value in this new column, which will return the date. Not elegant, but may work.

Comment: I was thinking more about just saving the start_time and the number of hours till the end_time. Or just use a 48 hour system per day. For example: 15:00-21:00 AND 22:00-26:00 but I can t save time like that (26:00)

Comment: @JaredFarrish the logic is simple. Inform the user that the shop is either OPEN or CLOSED (CAN order or CANNOT order).

Comment: Ohhh. Ok. You just want to stop sales on your website or through a POS system? Such as, somebody tries to put something in their shopping cart and they get a notification that the shop is closing and no more orders may be made?

Comment: @JaredFarrish that is correct!

Comment: Ok, I got something. All in the database, you just do a query. Let me write it up here in a minute.

Comment: The only overlap you're talking about is that, like a bartender, they work a little over into the next day? As in, the later schedule ins another shift?

Comment: The most difficult overlap is the example explained in my question. But it can occur in any given day. I could have overlaps for every day: Monday [16:00-01:30], Tuesday [16:00-01:30], .. , Sunday [12:00-16:00 && 20:00 - 04:00]. So yes, for each day, we could have at least one overlap. I came up with a solution, which is not the best practice for sure, works for many occasions, but not for all. I will post it as an answer right away but its chaotic..

Comment: Alright, I remembered something about MySQL I have read about but never used. It'll work, in fact was designed, for this very thing. Remember that you're seeing the *human* side of the equation, where there's part that's seemingly complex. But, if you get the right data and analyze it with the right tools, it's just numbers to the RDBMS. You'll see. I'm spec'ing out a test table with some dummy data right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was thinking:

```
CREATE TABLE Shifts (
  shift_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  start_day CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  start_time TIME NOT NULL,
  end_day CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
  end_time TIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now that I think about it, I'm not really sure you even need `end_day`. However, using:

```
INSERT INTO Shifts (
  start_day,
  start_time,
  end_day,
  end_time
) VALUES
( LOWER('Sunday'), '15:00:00', LOWER('Sunday'), '18:30:00' ),
( LOWER('Sunday'), '21:00:00', LOWER('Monday'), '26:30:00' ),
( LOWER('Monday'), '12:00:00', LOWER('Monday'), '18:00:00' ),
( LOWER('Tuesday'), '10:00:00', LOWER('Tuesday'), '20:45:00' ),
( LOWER('Wednesday'), '16:00:00', LOWER('Wednesday'), '19:30:00' ),
( LOWER('Thursday'), '10:00:00', LOWER('Thursday'), '17:00:00' ),
( LOWER('Thursday'), '19:00:00', LOWER('Friday'), '25:30:00' ),
( LOWER('Friday'), '16:00:00', LOWER('Saturday'), '24:30:00' ),
( LOWER('Saturday'), '15:00:00', LOWER('Saturday'), '20:00:00' ),
( LOWER('Saturday'), '18:30:00', LOWER('Sunday'), '27:00:00' )
```

You could then use something like the following:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(NOW()), start_day
FROM Shifts
WHERE (start_day = LOWER(DAYNAME(NOW()))
       AND start_time < CURTIME()
       AND end_time > CURTIME())
   OR (start_day = LOWER(DAYNAME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))
       AND start_time < ADDTIME('24:00:00', CURTIME())
       AND end_time > ADDTIME('24:00:00', CURTIME()))
```

Which you can test out here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41a26/34

And try it with different test values:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(NOW()), start_day
FROM Shifts
WHERE (start_day = LOWER('Friday')
       AND start_time < '01:12:35'
       AND end_time > '01:12:35')
   OR (start_day = LOWER('Thursday')
       AND start_time < ADDTIME('24:00:00', '01:12:35')
       AND end_time > ADDTIME('24:00:00', '01:12:35'))
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/41a26/33

Comment: This is the case of extending the time more than 24 hours for a shift. Just needs some tweaks when submitting the shifts into the database. I am testing it right now. Also as I am looking at it, if 2 different shifts overlap, then 2 or more rows return by the query, which is OK.

Comment: Seems to work as expected!! Last question, as SQL is out of my league on this level. @Jared Farrish how can we alter the query to use GMT or UTC based timestamp instead of plain NOW() and CURTIME() ?

Comment: @mallix - Sorry, I was out of town for the holidays. Do you mean how to inject your day/time into the query? You can do this with PHP [using `date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), for instance [matching the bottom example](http://codepad.org/xoos3r6A). MySQL also has [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). That last MySQL link has lots of different functions to work with date/time stamps as well.

Comment: Also, to your question about more than one result, the way you order the results can help if you want to get the last open, for example using `ORDER BY start_time, end_time DESC LIMIT 0, 1`, which should give you the latest shift result. Also, keep in mind the time on the database may differ from what you have locally in your server, and that you DO NOT want to allow shifts to begin after `23:59`; that should always be the next day, so you need to validate before saving a shift start time.

Comment: Thank you @Jared Farrish . I will have your tips in mind. I mean how to set the NOW() and CURTIME() to match each user s timezone. I could do that using php before passing the query to MYSQL as you stated. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function shop_open(){
    //Get current day
    $day = $this->_get_current_day();

    //Get current time
    $timeString = "%H:%i:%s";
    $ordertime = mdate($timeString, time());
    //Predefine ability to order to false
    $canOrder = false;

    $getShift = $this->db->query("select * from `shop_hours` where `day_of_week` = $day AND !ISNULL(`open_time`) ORDER BY `type`");
    $day_num_rows = $getShift->num_rows();

    switch($day_num_rows){
        case 0: //No records
            $canOrder = false;
            break;

        case 1: //Only 1 timeframe
            foreach($getShift->result() as $row){
                $open_time = $row->open_time;
                $close_time = $row->close_time;
            }

            if($open_time <= $close_time){//Timeframe is within the same day [no overlap]

                if($open_time < $ordertime && $close_time > $ordertime){//Current time is within timeframe
                    $canOrder = true;
                }else{
                    $canOrder = false;
                }

            }else if($open_time > $close_time){//There s your overlap [timframe "catches" the next day]

                if($open_time < $ordertime && '23:59' >= $ordertime){//Check till midnight first
                    $canOrder = true;
                }else{//Check in the previous day

                    if($day == 1){ $previousDay = 7; }else{ $previousDay = $day-1; }

                    $getPrvDayShift = $this->db->query("select * from `shop_hours` where `day_of_week` = $previousDay ORDER BY `type`");
                    $prv_day_num_rows = $getPrvDayShift->num_rows();

                    switch($prv_day_num_rows){
                        case 0://No records
                            $canOrder = false;
                            break;
                        case 1://One record found
                            foreach($getPrvDayShift->result() as $row2){
                                $prv_close_time = $row2->close_time;
                            }

                            if($prv_close_time > $ordertime){ //So if the previous day close time is greater than current, we are good to go
                                $canOrder = true;
                            }else{
                                $canOrder = false;
                            }

                            break;
                        case 2: //2nd record found
                            foreach($getPrvDayShift->result() as $row2){
                                if($row2->type == 2){
                                    $prv_close_time = $row2->close_time;
                                }
                            }
                            if($prv_close_time > $ordertime){ //Same shit, different timeframe within the same day 
                                $canOrder = true;
                            }else{
                                $canOrder = false;
                            }
                            break;
                    }

                }

            }
            break;

        case 2: //Ok now we have to check the case of 2 timeframes together

            for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
                foreach($getShift->result() as $row){
                    if($row->type == $i){
                        $open_time = $row->open_time;
                        $close_time = $row->close_time;
                    }
                }
                if($open_time <= $close_time){//Again, same day [no overlap]
                    if($open_time < $ordertime && $close_time > $ordertime){//Good to go we are within timeframe
                        $canOrder = true;
                    }else{
                        $canOrder = false;
                    }
                }else if($open_time > $close_time){//There s your overlap
                    //Check till midnight
                    if($open_time < $ordertime && '23:59' >= $ordertime){ $canOrder = true; }
                }
            }

            if(!$canOrder){
                //Now we should check the previous day also if $canOrder is still negative
                if($day == 1){ $previousDay = 7; }else{ $previousDay = $day-1; }
                $getPrvDayShift = $this->db->query("select * from `shop_hours` where `day_of_week` = $previousDay ORDER BY `type`");
                $prv_day_num_rows = $getPrvDayShift->num_rows();

                switch($prv_day_num_rows){
                    case 0:
                        $canOrder = false;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        foreach($getPrvDayShift->result() as $row2){
                            $prv_close_time = $row2->close_time;
                        }
                        if($prv_close_time > $ordertime){ $canOrder = true; }else{ $canOrder = false; }

                        break;
                    case 2:
                        foreach($getPrvDayShift->result() as $row2){
                            if($row2->type == 2){
                                $prv_close_time = $row2->close_time;
                            }
                        }
                        if($prv_close_time > $ordertime){ $canOrder = true; }else{ $canOrder = false; }
                        break;
                }
            }

            break;
    }
    return $canOrder;
}
```

$this->_get_current_day() is in my question.

I guess that there must be a more elegant and safe solution.

Comment: Holy cow. That's, uh, pretty detailed.

Comment: What jogged my memory were the [PHP `Date/Time` functions and objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). Take a look at those. If for some reason you decide you don't want the database to do what comes naturally to it, then you really should check out those functions and objects.

Comment: I'm still here, it's just coming up with plausible data like you've mentioned and doing it serially for ll shifts that week is making me think.

Answer (score 0):

In order to distinguish the timeframes that extends into the next day from the ones that does not, no timeframe can span more than 24 hours. Thus the closing time of these timeframes must be less then or equal to the opening time.

This query should then find the open shift(s) at a given time:

```
SELECT shift_id
FROM shifts
WHERE :curDay = day_of_week   
AND :curTime >= open_time                                -- today
AND (:curTime <= close_time OR close_time <= open_time)  -- shift may end tomorrow
OR :curDay = IF(day_of_week=1,7,day_of_week-1)           -- check yesterday
AND :curTime <= close_time AND close_time <= open_time   -- shift started yesterday
```

If possible I would change the table to split the shifts spanning midnight into two shifts, one ending at 24:00, the other starting at 00:00 the next day.

Comment: Interesting approach. You mean that no timeframe can span more than 23:59 or in general more than 24 hours ?

Comment: @malix Given you table definition, you would not be able to distinguish between a timeframe that spans only one day, and one that is longer than 24 hours. (E.g. from 10:00 to 14:00 today, and from 10:00 today until 14:00 tomorrow). Thus, you will have to assume that all timeframes are 24 h or less. Then timeframes that ends 'before' they start are extending into the next day.

Comment: 10:00 to 14:00 always means "the same day" for my system. When opentime < closetime, we are good. When opentime > closetime, means timeframe spans to the next day.

Comment: @mallix That is what I thought. Then my suggested query should do the job.

Comment: Thank you @Terje D. I ll give your query a try based on my db design and I will come back with the results.